# Firebase URL to Database node stopped working on Dec. 1st

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Since Dec. 1st, I am not able to access a Firebase Database node directly with a URL. It throws me back to the Console Homepage.

Is anyone else seeing this same problem? What's the workaround or way to resolve this?

For instance, if I try to browse:

```
https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com
```

It takes me to the Console homepage. I also tried the new URL and that does not seem to work either:

```
    https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firebase-myfirebasedomain/overview
```

Comment: I just tested and can still access the legacy dashboard for my legacy Firebase projects without problems. Are you seeing any errors in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I see this error in the console: The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.

Comment: I don't get any such warning (in Chrome 54), so that might indeed be related.

Comment: Firebase had a transient issue that they emailed me about, and is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase had a transient issue that they emailed me about, and is now fixed.